# Swipe Controls Issue

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, touch

I'm new to programming.I'm making a test game to learn how to use the touch controls in Unity.

So a ball(sphere) is my object that i am testing on.So I've written a code in which i want when i swipe in a specific direction the ball to move towards it.Like if i swipe right to move right,if i swipe left to move left.The same with the up and down direction.

So it is working but it doesn't respond immediately at my command.I mean if i make a little swipe it won't respond.I have to make a long swipe and put a pressure on the screen so it can change direction.Sometimes in this way doesn't respond either.

Or if i swipe left and then down the ball stops i don't know why?
I've been searching a lot but i haven't found my answer.

This is my code that I'm using:

```
public PlayerMovement ball;

Rigidbody2D player;

public float movespeed;
public float up;
public float smoothTime;

float dragDistance;

Vector2 targetVelocity;

Vector3 fp;
Vector3 lp;

List<Vector3> touchPositions = new List<Vector3>();

void Start () {
    player = ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    targetVelocity.x = movespeed;
    dragDistance = Screen.height * 20 / 100;

}


void Update () {

    foreach(Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {

        if(touch.phase==TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            touchPositions.Add(touch.position);
        }

        if(touch.phase==TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            fp = touchPositions[0];
            lp = touchPositions[touchPositions.Count - 1];

            if(Mathf.Abs(lp.x-fp.x)>dragDistance || Mathf.Abs(lp.y-fp.y)>dragDistance)
            {
                if(Mathf.Abs(lp.x-fp.x)>Mathf.Abs(lp.y-fp.y))
                {
                    if(lp.x>fp.x)
                    {
                        targetVelocity.x = movespeed;
                        targetVelocity.y = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        targetVelocity.x = -targetVelocity.x;
                        targetVelocity.y = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(lp.y>fp.y)
                    {
                        targetVelocity.y = up;
                        targetVelocity.x = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        targetVelocity.y = -targetVelocity.y;
                        targetVelocity.x = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


void FixedUpdate()
{





    player.velocity = Vector2.Lerp(player.velocity, targetVelocity, smoothTime);
}
```

}